# How to compile the C GNU Scientific Library (GSL) to web assembly using emscripten?

Tags: c, linker, webassembly, emscripten, gsl

The goal is to compile the latest stable [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) to [web assembly](https://webassembly.org/) and make it available as a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) module.

I tried the following procedure inspired by [this section of the emscripten manual](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html):

```sh
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/gsl.git
cd gsl
git checkout tags/release-2-6
autoreconf -i
emconfigure ./configure
emmake make
```

Unfortunately, I get multiple **`wasm-ld: error: duplicate symbol`**.

But compiling the GSL (`make`) works perfectly fine.

I am using `emsdk version 2.0.16` on Ubuntu 18.04.

Does anyone know, how to fix this problem?

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: That's a bit too generic question. What did you do to debug the error further? Did you check configs provided by GSL's ./configure and try to see if disabling any options helps?

Comment: Thank you @RReverser for your interest and feedback. I was fortunate to find a solution, almost by luck, I have to say. Have a look at the post below, if interested. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Finally found a solution inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rikvermeer/0caa80f7c507cd119a54ba0498a4ca84). The problem had to do with dynamic linking and shared libraries.

Anyway, the following code successfully compiles the GSL to a Node.js module:

```sh
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/gsl.git
cd gsl
git checkout tags/release-2-6
autoreconf -i
emconfigure ./configure

# Note the flag indicating STATIC linking:
# -------------------------======---------
emmake make LDFLAGS=-all-static

emcc -g -O2 -o .libs/gsl.js -s MODULARIZE -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=\[ccall\] -s LINKABLE=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1  ./.libs/libgsl.a -lm
```

The above creates the node module `./.libs/gsl.js` which can be used as shown in the following example script:

```js
// test_gsl.js

var factory = require('./.libs/gsl.js');

factory().then((instance) => {
  // Compute the value of the Bessel function for x = 5.0:
  var besselRes = instance._gsl_sf_bessel_J0(5.0);
  // Calculate the hypergeometric cumulative probability distribution for:
  // 4: Number of successes (white balls among the taken)
  // 7: Number of white balls in the urn
  // 19: Number of black balls in the urn
  // 13: Number of balls taken
  var hg = instance._gsl_cdf_hypergeometric_P(4, 7, 19, 13);
  // Do the same using `ccall`
  var hg_ccal = instance.ccall("gsl_cdf_hypergeometric_P",
    "number",
    ["number", "number", "number", "number" ],
    [4, 7, 19, 13]);
  console.log(`besselRes is: ${besselRes}`);
  console.log(`gsl_cdf_hypergeometric_P(4,7,19,13): ${hg}`);
  console.log(`ccall("gsl_cdf_hypergeometric_P",4,7,19,13): ${hg_ccal}`);
});
```

Please *note* that all GSL functions are prefixed with an underscore (`_`) in the generated Node.js module.

The above script (`node ./test_gsl.js`) generates this output:

```
besselRes is: -0.17759677131433826
gsl_cdf_hypergeometric_P(4,7,19,13): 0.8108695652173905
ccall("gsl_cdf_hypergeometric_P",4,7,19,13): 0.8108695652173905
```

I sincerely hope, this post helps any one.
Have a good one and Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

supplementing the [answer by user3139868](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67169806/19269732):

if you get some error regarding cblas symbol while running the last command:

```
emcc -g -O2 -o .libs/gsl.js -s MODULARIZE -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=\[ccall\] -s LINKABLE=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1  ./.libs/libgsl.a -lm
```

run the command below:

```
emcc -g -O2 -o .libs/gsl.js -s MODULARIZE -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=\[ccall\] -s LINKABLE=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1  ./cblas/.libs/libgslcblas.a .libs/libgsl.a -lm
```

---

***If you only want to compile a C++ program that uses GSL:***

Compile gsl:

```
git clone https://github.com/ampl/gsl
cd gsl
git checkout tags/v2.7.0
emconfigure ./configure && emmake make
```

(you will see errors about **duplicate symbol**, but that's ok, as long as **./.libs/libgsl.so.25** is produced)

Generate `example.js` and `example.wasm`:

for Ubuntu:

```
cd ../
emcc ./gsl/.libs/libgsl.so.25  example.cpp -I ./gsl -lm -o example.js -sMODULARIZE
```

for MacOS:

```
cd ../
emcc ./gsl/.libs/libgsl.25.dylib  example.cpp -I ./gsl -lm -o example.js -sMODULARIZE
```

Test:

```
node testGSL.js
```

You can find the `example.cpp` and `testGSL.js` files here:
https://github.com/cyavictor88/wasm-cpp/tree/main/gsl/cppWithGSL/